# How can I identify windows LDAP and linux LDAP using php?

Tags: php, linux, active-directory

I need to connect to an ldap server with php, but unfortunately I am not able to bind it with `ldap_bind()` method, as `ldap_connect()` always returns true.

I am using the example script available at [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/ldap.examples-basic.php)

I am having doubt that whether the ldap host is windows or not. How can I identify that by code?

**Code**

```
<?php
// basic sequence with LDAP is connect, bind, search, interpret search
// result, close connection

echo "<h3>LDAP query test</h3>";
echo "Connecting ...";
$ds=ldap_connect("localhost");  // must be a valid LDAP server!
echo "connect result is " . $ds . "<br />";

if ($ds) { 
    echo "Binding ..."; 
    $r=ldap_bind($ds);     // this is an "anonymous" bind, typically
                           // read-only access
    echo "Bind result is " . $r . "<br />";

    echo "Searching for (sn=S*) ...";

    // Search surname entry
    $sr=ldap_search($ds, "o=My Company, c=US", "sn=S*");  
    echo "Search result is " . $sr . "<br />";

    echo "Number of entries returned is " . ldap_count_entries($ds, $sr) . "<br />";

    echo "Getting entries ...<p>";
    $info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr);
    echo "Data for " . $info["count"] . " items returned:<p>";

    for ($i=0; $i<$info["count"]; $i++) {
        echo "dn is: " . $info[$i]["dn"] . "<br />";
        echo "first cn entry is: " . $info[$i]["cn"][0] . "<br />";
        echo "first email entry is: " . $info[$i]["mail"][0] . "<br /><hr />";
    }

    echo "Closing connection";
    ldap_close($ds);

} else {
    echo "<h4>Unable to connect to LDAP server</h4>";
}
?>
```

Comment: all code you are using add to your question please.

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo The code is added.

Comment: Now here if I use var_dump($r) then I am able to see that ldap_bind() returns false in my case

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27873735/5397119 there some explanation

Answer (score 0):

I met the problem before.maybe because of the version

`ldap_set_option($ds, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);`

I used this to solve it,you can try.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to determine whether the OS is windows or not you can use the php constant [PHP_OS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php#constant.php-os)

Here is a small example how a function `isWindows()` could look like:

```
function isWindows() {
    if( substr( strtolower( PHP_OS ), 0, 3 ) === 'win' ) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

var_dump( isWindows() );
```

Comment: This won't work in my case as the server on which I need to connect using LDAP is not same as server on which PHP is running.

Comment: Ok, im sorry didn't get that